# Using Twisted AMP with Database insertion

Tags: python, twisted

I am learning how to use Twisted AMP.  I am developing a program that sends data from a client to a server and inserts the data in a SQLite3 DB. The server then sends back a result to the client which indicates success or error (try and except might not be the best way to do this but it is only a temporary solution while I work out the main problem). In order to do this I modified an example I found that originally did a sum and returned the result, so I realize that this might not be the most efficient way to do what I am trying to do. In particular I am trying to do some timings on multiple insertions (i.e. send the data to the server multiple times for multiple insertions) and I have included the code I have written. It works but clearly it is not a good way to send multiple data for insertion since I am performing multiple connections before running the reactor.

I have tried several ways to get around this including passing the ClientCreator to  reactor.callWhenRunning() but you cannot do this with a deferred.

Any suggestions, advice or help with how to do this would be much appreciated. Here is the code.

Server:

```
from twisted.protocols import amp
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
import sqlite3, time

class Insert(amp.Command):
    arguments = [('data', amp.Integer())]
    response = [('insert_result', amp.Integer())]

class Protocol(amp.AMP):
    def __init__(self):     
       self.conn = sqlite3.connect('biomed1.db')
       self.c =self.conn.cursor()
       self.res=None

    @Insert.responder
    def dbInsert(self, data):
        self.InsertDB(data) #call the DB inserter
        result=self.res     # send back the result of the insertion
        return {'insert_result': result}

    def InsertDB(self,data):
      tm=time.time()
      print "insert time:",tm
      chx=data
      PID=2
      device_ID=5
      try:
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO btdata4(co2_data, patient_Id, sensor_Id) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')" % (chx, PID, device_ID))    
      except Exception, err:
             print err
             self.res=0
      else:
             self.res=1

      self.conn.commit()


pf = Factory()
pf.protocol = Protocol
reactor.listenTCP(1234, pf) 
reactor.run()
```

Client:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientCreator
from twisted.protocols import amp
import time

class Insert(amp.Command):
    arguments = [('data', amp.Integer())]
    response = [('insert_result', amp.Integer())]

def connected(protocol):
    return protocol.callRemote(Insert, data=5555).addCallback(gotResult)

def gotResult(result):
    print 'insert_result:', result['insert_result']
    tm=time.time()
    print "stop", tm    

def error(reason):
    print "error", reason

tm=time.time()
print "start",tm
for i in range (10): #send data over ten times
  ClientCreator(reactor, amp.AMP).connectTCP(
     '127.0.0.1', 1234).addCallback(connected).addErrback(error)

reactor.run()
```

End of Code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things which will improve your Server code.

First and foremost: The use of direct database access functions is discouraged in twisted, as they normally causes block. Twisted has nice abstraction for database access which provides twisted approach to db connection - [twisted.adbapi](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/rdbms.html)

Now on to reuse of db connection: If you want to reuse certain assets (like database connection) across a number of Protocol instances, you should initialize those in constructor of Factory or if you dont fancy initiating such things at a launch time, create an resource access method, which will initiate resource upon first method call then assign it to class variable and return that on subsequent calls.

When Factory creates a specific Protocol intance, it will add a reference to itself inside the protocol, see [line 97 of twisted.internet.protocol](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/internet/protocol.py#L97)

Then within your Protocol instance, you can access shared database connection instance like:

```
self.factory.whatever_name_for_db_connection.doSomething()
```

Reworked Server code (I dont have python, twisted or even decent IDE available, so this is pretty much untested, some errors are to be expected)

```
from twisted.protocols import amp
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
import time

class AMPDBAccessProtocolFactory(Factory):
    def getDBConnection(self):
        if 'dbConnection' in dir(self):
            return self.dbConnection
        else:
            self.dbConnection = SQLLiteTestConnection(self.dbURL)
            return self.dbConnection

class SQLLiteTestConnection(object):
    """
    Provides abstraction for database access and some business functions.
    """
    def __init__(self,dbURL):
        self.dbPool =  adbapi.ConnectionPool("sqlite3" , dbURL,  check_same_thread=False)

    def insertBTData4(self,data):
        query = "INSERT INTO btdata4(co2_data, patient_Id, sensor_Id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)" 
        tm=time.time()
        print "insert time:",tm
        chx=data
        PID=2
        device_ID=5
        dF = self.dbPool.runQuery(query,(chx, PID, device_ID)) 
        dF.addCallback(self.onQuerySuccess,insert_data=data)
        return dF
    def onQuerySuccess(self,insert_data,*r):
        """
        Here you can inspect query results or add any other valuable information to be parsed at client.
        For the test sake we will just return True to a customer if query was a success.
        original data available at kw argument insert_data
        """
        return True


class Insert(amp.Command):
    arguments = [('data', amp.Integer())]
    response = [('insert_result', amp.Integer())]

class MyAMPProtocol(amp.AMP):

    @Insert.responder
    def dbInsert(self, data):
        db = self.factory.getDBConnection()
        dF = db.insertBTData4(data)
        dF.addErrback(self.onInsertError,data)
        return dF

    def onInsertError(self, error, data):
        """
        Here you could do some additional error checking or inspect data 
        which was handed for insert here. For now we will just throw the same exception again
        so that the client gets notified
        """
        raise error

if __name__=='__main__':
    pf = AMPDBAccessProtocolFactory()
    pf.protocol = MyAMPProtocol
    pf.dbURL='biomed1.db'
    reactor.listenTCP(1234, pf) 
    reactor.run()
```

Now on to the client. IF AMP follows the overall RPC logic (cant test it currently) it should be able to peruse the same connection across a number of calls. So I have created a ServerProxy class which will hold that perusable protocol instance and provide abstraction for calls:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientCreator
from twisted.protocols import amp
import time

class Insert(amp.Command):
    arguments = [('data', amp.Integer())]
    response = [('insert_result', amp.Integer())]

class ServerProxy(object):
    def connected(self,protocol):
        self.serverProxy = protocol # assign protocol as instance variable
        reactor.callLater(5,self.startMultipleInsert) #after five seconds start multiple insert procedure

    def remote_insert(self,data):
        return self.serverProxy.callRemote(Insert, data)

    def startMultipleInsert(self):
        for i in range (10): #send data over ten times
            dF = self.remote_insert(i)
            dF.addCallback(self.gotInsertResult)
            dF.addErrback(error)

    def gotInsertResult(self,result):
        print 'insert_result:', str(result)
        tm=time.time()
        print "stop", tm    

def error(reason):
    print "error", reason


def main():
    tm=time.time()
    print "start",tm
    serverProxy = ServerProxy()
    ClientCreator(reactor, amp.AMP).connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 1234).addCallback(serverProxy.connected).addErrback(error)
    reactor.run()    

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I am currently working through your solution. I originally used the adbapi but what was happening was that by the time the adbapi returned the deferred, the AMP result had already returned a value. Basically I had two deferreds in series (the adbapi and the remote call) If I am waiting for the insert to complete from the client side then (as far as I can see) the adbapi gives no advantage. However, you might have found a way around this, so I will get your code running and see what happens. Many thanks.

Comment: I suspect that you are thinking about twisted process in standart linear code way. This was the major obstacle I had to overcome, when first starting on twisted projects. In twisted you can not think of your execution flow as being linear. Therefore - you can, for example do a multiple database calls in a rapid sequence without waiting for their reply on the next line. Wherever you receive deferred, you have not executed anything yet (in most cases), you have put a job out for execution.

Comment: I am new to Twisted so you are right. I ran your code and got this error:  File "DBAserver4.py", line 48, in dbInsert
    db = self.protocol.getDBConnection()
exceptions.AttributeError: 'MyAMPProtocol' object has no attribute 'protocol' - I tried various things to make it work but to no avail. I did a hack and was able to run but it got hung on the query format, which I will play around with. But I cannot see why it does not see the protocol in MyAMPProtocol. Thanks again.

Comment: That worked. I should have thought to try that. I'll work on the query format and it should run through. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the query format, also changed the Insert response to amp.Boolean and the format of the return in dbInsert to match the Insert response format. In normal operation I saw the True (onQuerySuccess) on the client side. However, even if I change the return to False in onQuerySuccess I still get a True sent back to the client. Also, if I generate an error in the query string the errBack  onInsertError does not capture it. I tried a number of work arounds but no solution. I will keep trying. I can re-post with changes to code if you are interested.

Comment: Correction - the errBack onInsertError does get called but the problem is that I have to use a amp.Boolean() for the response in the Insert(amp.Command) class to respond with a True for the dF when there is a successful insert. But when the error is raised in onInsertError the error is not sent back to the client if I am using the amp.Boolean() but only if I use amp.Integer() but of course this will not work on success. I tried using an error response in the Insert(amp.Command) class but it does not recognize the sqlite errors. Other than this the program works.

Comment: You could always return False in MyAMPProtocol.onInsertError instead of rethrowing the same exception. However I am not a fan of sweeping errors under the rug. When looking at http://amp-protocol.net/ it seems that it DOES provide mechanism for specifying errors in specific amp.Command implementation by adding another class variable named errors. Take a look at that perhaps it will solve your issue. If sqlite errors are too much to enlist there, you can always wrap that error in your own Exception implemenation.

Comment: That is a good idea. I think that is the best way to go. Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: If the answers helped dont forget to close the thread by accepting answer.  And no prob helping you : as I have moved away from code for a while now,  this helps me to keep the knowledge and sharpen brain a bit.